# Get an error when verify the mock test in asp dot net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, mstest, stackexchange.redis

```
private Mock<Icache<string>> _mockobj;

[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    _mockobj = new Mock<Icache<string>>();
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task methodName()
{
    _mockobj.Setup(x => x.get("keyname", out id)).Returns(true);
    _mockobj.Verify(x => x.get("keyname", out id), Times.Once());
}
```

Got an error on the verify statement the error is

> Evaluation of method System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call requires calling method System.RuntimeType.get_IsCollectible
> , which cannot be called in this context.

Comment: As the exception's message said your mock is not in use. You have to provide the mock to your system under test, like `sut(_mockobj.Object);` which will call in your case the `get` method with the specified parameters.

Comment: What is `Icache`?

Comment: Yes using Icache

Comment: @PeterCsala can you please more elaborate because in above example how to provide mock and one question my cache related implementation in middleware not in controller or  any business logic file that’s impact the testcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of brevity let's suppose we have the following stuffs:

```
public interface ICache<T>
{
    void Get(string key, out T value);
}
```

```
class SystemUnderTest
{
    private readonly ICache<string> cache;

    public SystemUnderTest(ICache<string> cache)
      => this.cache = cache;

    public void MethodUnderTest()
      => cache.Get("key", out var _);
}
```

So, the `SystemUnderTest` (SUT) class receives an `ICache` instance via constructor and uses it inside its `MethodUnderTest`.

Then your should look something like this:

```
//Arrange
var cacheMock = new Mock<ICache<string>>();
var expectedOutValue = "value";
cacheMock.Setup(c => c.Get("key", out expectedOutValue));

//Act
var sut = new SUT(cacheMock.Object);
sut.MethodUnderTest();

//Assert
cacheMock.Verify(c => c.Get("key", out expectedOutValue));
```

- In the Arrange phase we setup the mock
- In the Act phase we connect the mock and the SUT, then we call the method which uses the mock
- Finally in the Assert phase we verify the usage of the mock

---

**UPDATE #1**

> When in act method have a another api calling what will do for that part, now that api returns null.

There must be always a **single act**.
No matter what, you should test only one aspect of your code.

Most of the time when you have to call another component to "initialize" something for the system under test that means it is an *indirect dependency*. If you can't mock it, then you should do it as a part of the preparation (arrange phase(s)).

At some extent the AAA "pattern" can be extended with further steps like this:

- Arrange for SUT
- Arrange for non-mockable dependency
- Verify non-mockable dependency
- Act
- Assert

which could bring clarity for future maintainer of the test

Comment: Thank you Peter Csala  for the solution, I missed the act in mock test.

Comment: @KrishnaSoni Yes, that's what I tried to say in the comment :)

Comment: I have one more question when in act method have a another api calling what will do for that part, now that api return null.

Comment: @KrishnaSoni Sorry for the late response I was on holiday. Please check my updated post.